# Hilbert scheme of Grassmannians

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, hilbert-schemes

Let $X=\mathbb{G}(k,n)$ be the Grassmannian of $k$-planes in $n$-space. Let $Y\subseteq X$ a subvariety and let $H$ be the connected component of the Hilbert scheme of $X$ that contains $Y$.

1. Is $H$ even linearly connected?

**Edit: The following has already been satisfactorily answered by a comment of abx.**

Now let $Y$ be a locally complete intersection and $H^1(Y,\mathcal{N})=0$, where $\mathcal{N}$ is the normal sheaf of $Y$ in $X$.

2. Is in this case $H$ nonsingular at $Y$ of dimension $h^0(Y,\mathcal{N})$?

I know that both are true in the case where $X=\mathbb{P}^n$, so I hoped that at least for Grassmannians it might be true as well.

Comment: 2. is true for any $X$ quasi-projective (this goes back to Grothendieck, *les schémas de Hilbert*, exp. 221 of the Bourbaki seminar (1961), Corollaire 5.4).